# "I want it rather than him" could mean

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

The sentence "I want it rather than him" could mean

1. I want to have it rather than him having it
2. I want to have it rather than to have him

Or are both meanings possible?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as structured means just one thing:

> I want to have it rather than to have him.

*Him*, like *it*, functions as a direct object of *want*.

Depending on the larger conversation in which the original shorthand statement is made, it is possible that a listener would understand the meaning to be your No. 1 choice

> I want to have it rather than him having it.

but, while grammatically this may be clearer than the shorthand statement, it is not really idiomatic.

A more natural statement would be:

> I want to have it *more* than [I want] him to have it

or

> I want to have it *more* than to have him get it

or some such.

In other words, we typically say *I want X rather than Y*, in which X and Y are direct objects; we do not typically say *I want X rather than [I want] Y*, which combines two clauses. At least I never have. And you can't really say

> I want it more than him

because that will be taken to mean *I want it more than he wants it*.

So to get to your first interpretation, the listener has not only to overlook the grammatical error (which is easily done), but also to overlook the idiomatic error (which is not so easily done).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I want to have it rather than him having it
> 2. I want to have it rather than to have him

"I want it more than he" gets the first one across.
"I want it more than him" is the second one.

From Grammar Girl:

> Here's another example. Conjunctionists would argue that the sentences
>   *Aardvark likes Squiggly more than I* and *Aardvark likes Squiggly more
>   than me* are both correct but have entirely different meanings. Both
>   use *than* as a conjunction, but when you use the subject pronoun *I*,
>   you're saying *Aardvark likes Squiggly more than I [like Squiggly]*, and
>   when you use the object pronoun *me*, you're saying *Aardvark likes
>   Squiggly more than [Aardvark likes] me*.

- See more at: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/than-i-versus-than-me#sthash.VmINrpoQ.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it could mean both. However, when speaking, this sentence doesn't sound right. To mean "I want it and he doesn't", one could say "I, as apposed to him, want it". To mean "I want that thing, not him", one would add a comma, saying "I want it, rather than him". Either situation is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The written sentence is ambiguous. Spoken out loud each meaning is possible.

1

> **I** want it: rather than him. =( **I** want it rather than [let] him [have it])

2

> I want ( **it** rather than **him** )